# How to add ScrollView in Android XML?

Tags: android, xml

I am making an Image Gallery, I want to Scroll the Entire Layout, So what should i add in this code, and where should i add those things ?
I am making an Image Gallery, I want to Scroll the Entire Layout, So what should i add in this code, and where should i add those things ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5sp"
     >


<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall1" />
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall2" />
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall3" />
    </LinearLayout>  


<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall4" />
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall5" />
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall6" />
    </LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall7" />
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall8" />
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall9" />
    </LinearLayout> 

<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall10" />
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall11" />
    <ImageView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wall12" />
    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ScrollView` needs to have exactly **one child view** so creating one either by using the graphical tool and dragging it to your layout or writing the appropriate xml in your layout file and then moving all the items you want to inside that one child view should do.

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
            ALL YOUR IMAGES AND STUFF HERE
      </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to grpaphical layout right  click on layout which you want to wrap in scrollview select wrap in container and then scrollview
Scrollview can have only one direct child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5sp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall5" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall6" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall7" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall8" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall9" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall10" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall11" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="123dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wall12" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the entire layout to scroll then you have to set **ScrollView** as the root element in your layout file. Note that scrollview can only support one direct child element.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  >
<LinearLayout  //only one direct child
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- as many clildren as you want here -->
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```